# syntax error from external javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call an external .js file which will place text into one of my 's.

The script works perfectly when included in the index.php, but when using the following:

```
<script src="js/updates.js"></script>
```

into the index.php, it returns a syntax error in the updates.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

setInterval(chatStatus(),3000);

function chatStatus()
{
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById('chatStatus').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "phprequests/chatStatus.php", true);  <------ this line returns syntax error.
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. How comes this returns syntax error outside of the index.php file?

Comment: are you sure that it's the JS code that's at fault, and it's not a PHP syntax error being returned as the result of trying to open that url? what EXACTLY is the error message?

Comment: and note that if you're loading an external .js file, you do **NOT** put `<script>` tags in that file. it needs to be pure JS.

Comment: The error message is: "There is a syntax error on line 17 of updates.js. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error.".

Comment: @MarcB I will try your second comment, one second.

Comment: @MarcB it worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the script headers from the external .js file solved the issue.

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

setInterval(chatStatus(),3000);

function chatStatus()
{
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById('chatStatus').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "phprequests/chatStatus.php", true);  <------ this line returns syntax error.
xmlhttp.send();
}
```